# how to merge / extend unallocated space? (Not dual os)

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ssd

I have been reading posts and they were talking about using GParted and drag it but it seems different here.

I don't have dual OS.

Currently bought a bigger sshd and cloned by smaller ssd into it using clonezilla.

I thought by doing so, it'll also make the spaces bigger automatically but eneded up, it cloned the way ssd's partition is too so now in my new sshd there's a big unallocated spaces unaccounted for.

How can I merge / extend this though?

[image: GParted]

This is what happens for the last step
[image]

weird, why is my property still having the old capacity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, I take it you are already using a live medium to run gparted. That's the correct first step.

Assuming you want to increase the size of /dev/sdb1 from the unallocated space at the bottom, you need to do the following:

- right-click on /dev/sdb5 (the swap partition) and choose `swapoff`. This will unmount the partition so you can move things around. Otherwise gparted will refuse to take action on a mounted partition.
- right-click on /dev/sdb2 (the extended partition) and choose `move/resize`. Use the dialog to move the huge unused space at the bottom ahead of /dev/sdb2.
- right-click on /dev/sdb5 and choose `swapon`.
- right-click on /dev/sdb1, choose `move/resize`, and grow the partition to the desired space.

gparted allows you to queue several actions before proceeding, or you can take it one step at a time. Personally, I prefer the 2nd option by hitting the apply button (the check mark) after each step.

---

This is based on the added screenshot. In step 2, instead of moving the space before /dev/sdb2, you moved it inside /sdb2. In restrospect, I should have worded it more clearly.

No problem, just do the following:

- if /dev/sdb5 is mounted, then unmount it with swapoff.
- right-click /dev/sdb2 to `move/resize`, this time make sure the free space is before /dev/sdb2. Before clicking apply, visually inspect the updated graphics that the free space is between sdb1 and sdb2.
- expand sdb1 (like in the original last step).

---

GParted 101:

In the move/resize dialog, there are up/down controls beside each text entry box. You can use these to fine-tune where the disk spaces should go. In addition, you can manually type over the text (numbers) with the desired amount of space (in megabytes).

Note: if you type over a number, you have to press enter so the corresponding changes to the other fields are made. Play around with these controls (arrows and text fields) until you get the desired result. When I say "move the space to the top" I meant you as the user must do so, using the controls provided in the dialog.

GParted, whether on an ubuntu live disk or gparted live, will work exactly the same way. You have to specify what you want to happen. It will not automagically know what you want to do.

As a last resort, click `Help > Contents`on the menu for a detailed documentation on how gparted works. I read it before when I was a newbie and it was fairly exhaustive.

Comment: the last step wouldn't work though

Comment: no errors, just when I click on sda1, and the `move/resize` it's already max can't drag like how it used to be

Comment: Edited, and yes I thought the steps are so easy esp the last one but donno where I went wrong :(

Comment: this sounds super easy but somehow the unallocated isn't moved to between sdb1 and sdb2. P.S. am I being stupid and should use GParted live and boot with it? I am actually running GParted inside the OS

Comment: sorry just one more question, I can see in GParted that it's already now using the whole spaces but when I check computer property, why does it still say the capacity is 500GB? the old capacity